# How to make a model Field take 2 values from two different drop down lists in Django

Tags: python, django

I am designing the models for a tutor page and I was wondering how to make a model field take two values from two different drop down lists and make them into one and the save that to the database.

My objective is to make an availability model field which takes the day that a tutor is available to work from one dropdown list, and the available time that he is able to work on that day from the second dropdown list, and also the ability to add more than one day that the tutor is available. Something that would return this in shell.

```
>>>tutor1.available_time
(('Monday','after 4pm'),('Tuesday','In the Morning'),('Friday','after 2pm'),)
>>>tutor2.available_time
(('AnyDay','after 12pm'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really just want to use a single field, use a text field and store JSON encoded lists in it.

Alternatively, create a new model with two fields and make a foreign key from tutors to the new model.